# php script that populates photos to a html div

Tags: php

I currently have a picture page with about 250 jpeg. Images and I currently have a web page where I manually assigned a picture to a section on the page, however this is very time consuming and would like to create a script that will run through and assign the images to a div. While this normally would be easy my problem is the way they filed the images. On the web page I have a quad drawling, and each portion of the quad needs a image assigned to it. the image file names vary and is causing my headache:

The file format Ex is below. so each quad would have 4 images, the first set of numbers before the underscore is the pict id and the number in between the underscores is which section of the quad the pict goes to. But the pict id vary in length and I’m not sure how to go about this. Any thoughts or recommendations are appreciated.

- 1234_1_01.jpeg
- 1234_2_03.jpeg
- 1234_3_02.jpeg
- 1234_4_01.jpeg
- 345422_1_01.jpeg
- 345422_2_02.jpeg and so on

Comment: How do you know what images are shown?  Is it all the images in a certain folder?  Can you post a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a sample HTML showing one of these "quads drawlings"?

Comment: `preg_match('/^(\d+)_(\d)_(\d+).jpg$/')` for a quick/dirty capturing of the 3 number sets in the filename.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the actually quad but for a mental image just think of a rifle scope and when you look in it you have a circle and a cross with 4 sections. all photos are in a folder. Below is a little sample code that I started on. This just calls a image from the image folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to go through the whole folder and filter the pictures accordingly like so:

```
$myPicFolder = "path/to/pictures/";
$thePics = array();
if (is_dir($myPicFolder)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($myPicFolder)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)) {
            if(!is_dir($myPicFolder . $file){
                list($intersectionID,$section,$imgID) = explode('_'.$file);//Seperates the parts of the name for easier access
                //check if the ID is already a key in $thePics
                if(!array_key_exists($intersectionID,$thePics)){
                    //Add the new ID if it does not exist with an empty array.
                    $thePics[$intersectionID]=array();
                }
                if(!array_key_exists($section,$thePics[$intersectionID])){
                    //Add the new ID if it does not exist with an empty array.
                    $thePics[$intersectionID][$section]=array();
                }
                // Add a new part to the ID since each picture ID has 4 pictures.
                $thePics[$intersectionID][$section][] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}


//$thePics will then look like:
// array('1234'=>array(
//        '1'=>'1234_1_01.jpeg',
//        '2'=>'1234_2_03.jpeg',
//        '3'=>'1234_3_02.jpeg',
//        '4'=>'1234_4_01.jpeg'),
//    '345422'=>array(
//        '1'=>'345422_1_01.jpeg',
//        '2'=>'345422_2_02.jpeg')
//    );

//Cycle through the pictures...
foreach($thePics as $pictureID=>$quad){
    echo '<div class="intersection">';
    foreach($quad as $quadPart=>$pictures){
        echo '<div class=”s1”>';
        foreach($pictures as $pictureSRC){
            echo '<img src="'.$pictureSRC.'"/>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Please remember to do some more verifications on the file natures to make sure you are only sending pictures... Maybe test on file extension and mime type...

EDIT: Added some comments and used list() to give explicit names to the variables I am using for better understanding.

Comment: I keep on getting a error on    if(!is_dir($myPictFolder. $file)

Comment: Sorry im new to this as well could you explain to me what this part of the code is acually doing..I appriciate your help  if(!array_key_exists($nameParts[0],$thePics))$thePics[$nameParts[0]]=array();
     $thePics[$nameParts[0]][$nameParts[1]] = $file;

Comment: What is the error? If it says $myPictFolder is undefined, it is because you put a "t" at pict... but copy/pasting should not throw an error...

As for the second question, I have added explaination in the answer.

Comment: Ok, now if you adjust the path to your pictures, and the HTML markup to fit yours it will work 100%.

Comment: Thank you for the help and comments but i still get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\co\subco\photo_code\test.php on line 19 this is refering to this part of the code:   if(!is_dir($myPicFolder . $file){

Comment: I just realized that A ) bracket was missing at the end. The error went away but now a blank screen pops up with no results

Comment: Ok so after doing some error checking with echo calls before the foreach I then get a error saying $file undefined so something is going wrong with the accessing the directory. So I changed how i accessed the directory and now I get just one broken image symbol any ideas?

Comment: Corrected a type. Verify your path, I think you are not getting into the right directory. Before the foreach, add var_dump($thePics); this will print out a human readable representation of the array contents. This will allow you to see how populated it is for troubleshooting.

Comment: I cant thank you enough Salketer that worked for me, my images still came up as broken images, so I added the dir  path within the <img src call and it worked

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. Glad to be of help! Don't forget to choose my answer :)

Comment: Sorry for this Salketer but I have one more question for you. Conceptually I am having a hard time understanding How to select out a 1 quad photo and assign it to a div. I have tried the search function/and I have tried a setting a variable with the number i am trying to select out and used it in a if statement but i keep on getting nulls.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean. Have you tried using var_dump($thePics); To see what the array looks like? It might help you figure out the way you need to grab the variables afterwards... Or else post your code somewhere so I can troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes I did a Var_dump($thePics) and the output looks like the output you posted above.I guess my problem is understanding how to select out one of the Picture ids(say 345422 from the array as well as selecting out each quad id  and assign that quad to a Div.

Comment: See the modification in the foreach to access the $pictureID and $quadPart (1 to 4)

Comment: Salketer,
I want to thank you greatly for your help so far.  I think we are very close, but I wanted to take a minute and step back to more thoroughly explain our goal. We have a directory of some 3,000 photographs (.jpg).  They are countywide photos of road intersections.  Each intersection can have several (varying count) “sections” and each section can have multiple photos (also varying count). The photos have been named with the following convention - ID_SEC_IMG#, where: ID = numeric identifier that identifies the image as belonging to a particular intersection.

Comment: Within the intersection, it is then broken into multiple sections (potential of 12 unique sections within each intersection).  Each section then can have multiple photos.  So the folder may look like this…   

    117_1_1.jpg  where 117=intersection ID; 1=Section #; 1=Image #
    117_1_2.jpg
    117_1_3.jpg
    117_2_1.jpg
    117_3_1.jpg
    117_4_1.jpg
    117_4_2.jpg
    117_4_3.jpg
    117_4_4.jpg

Comment: What we need to do is:
1. Find all photos in the folder that belong to a particular intersection ID that will be pass into a $sigID (117) variable via an <a> link on a separate page;
2. Of those photos, read out the Section # and display all photos with Section #1 in <div class=”s1”>; all photos with Section #2 in <div class=”s2”>; and so on.
3. Then ensure to iterate (and echo) all images that match the first 2 criteria to ensure a complete dump of all photos for the intersection within the proper div based on section.

Comment: Resulting in markup as follows:

<div class=”s1”><img src=”117_1_1.jpg” /><img src=”117_1_2.jpg” /><img src=”117_1_3.jpg” /></div>
<div class=”s2”><img src=”117_2_1.jpg” /></div>
…and so on.

I feel like we are so close.  With the code you’ve provided me thus far I am able to loop through those photos that meet the first criteria, but when I do a var_dump on $quad, I only get the last photo in the intersection/section combo applied to $quad.  (Ex. 117_1_3.jpg, 117_2_1.jpg, 117_3_1.jpg, 117_4_4.jpg)

Comment: Again I appreciate your help with all of this.  I’m still learning PHP and trying to strengthen my OOP skills.  I feel like I understand what I need to accomplish, I’m just lacking the wherewithal to

Comment: Since you want to have more than on picture per "quad", change the code to make the key"quad" into an array... I have made the changes to my answer... You should have been more explicit in your question :)

Comment: Great thank you again. From what I have been reading, to send a variable from  the web page to this script I can use <a href="photo_pg.php?sigID=1715"> and from there use a $_GET method  on the php script. My problem now how to find just the picture id stated in  Href and its corresponding quad photos. Im having trouble   understanding how to integrate the conditional statement. Change made above..

Comment: $thePics[$_GET['sigID']]; will give you the list of quads. Remove the bigger foreach and replace $quad by that. This will be my last interaction on this question as it is becoming more of a tutorial on how to work with PHP than a realy question/answer thing. Please read tutorials to start learning more in PHP, and you will catch up real fast from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$test = '1234_1_01.jpeg';
list($pict_id, $quad_id) = explode('_', $test);
echo "Pict ID: $pict_id<br />
      Quad ID: $quad_id";
```