# Explode, middle character

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php script that populates photos to a html div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320343/php-script-that-populates-photos-to-a-html-div)

After looking at php manual I still cant seem to find how to pull just one character out of this file name. I have a list of file names that vary in lengh and are broken up by a under score
Ex. 
12321_1_23
543_2_34

Ive tried this code to get a feel for what it is doing but this just breaks each section:

```
$example = explode( "_",$test);
```

Is there a way to just get the character inbetween the underscores?

Comment: yes i could not get the code to work for me so im trying a new approach with the way the files are stored

Comment: If you middle character is always the second #: list(, $num) = explode('_', '12321_1_23'); echo $num;

Comment: Did you examine `$example`? (Hint: no)

Comment: What @apprentice tries to say is that $example[1] will hold the middle character.